# PHP Eval variable and set another variable

Tags: php

If I have a string like this:
`0+1+0+0+0+0+0+1+0+1+1+1+1+0+0+1+0+1+1+1+1+0+0+1+0+0+1+0+0+0+0+0+0+1+1+0+1+1+0+0+0+1+1+0+1+1+0+1+0+1+1+0+0+0+0+1+0+1+1+0+1+1+1+1`

I need it do actually do the math.

So if `$a = '0+1+0+0+0+0+0+1'`
It would set another variable and set it as:
`2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never `eval` strings if you can help it. There's a trivial sane solution for parsing and summing this particular string:

```
$string = '0+1+...';
$result = array_sum(explode('+', $string));
```

If you want to support more possible operations than just `+`, you'd do a slightly more complex `preg_split`, then loop over the resulting items and evaluate each individual operator and sum or subtract or whatever based on the encountered operator in a loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helps. I know `eval` is bad, it was the really first solution that came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php `eval` function as follows.

```
<?php
$string="0+1+0+0+0+0+0+1+0+1+1+1+1+0+0+1+0+1+1+1+1+0+0+1+0+0+1+0+0+0+0+0+0+1+1+0+1+1+0+0+0+1+1+0+1+1+0+1+0+1+1+0+0+0+0+1+0+1+1+0+1+1+1+1";

eval("\$val=$string;");
var_dump($val);
?>
```

This will output `int(31)` which is the sum of the integers in the string

Comment: lets hope its not a user submitted string